# Consider a convex polyhedra such that Euler's Polyhedra Formula applies...

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

Consider the proposition of Euler that V - E + F = 2 for polyhedra. It is famously known that Euler's original proof failed to preserve convexity when considering the removal of vertices from polyhedra by means of removing pyramids from the polyhedra--to arrive at a simple tetrahedron.

Or, rather, that his process for the removal of vertices could lead to non-convex polyhedra, or even degenerate polyhedra. Provide an example using a hexagonal pyramid stacked onto a hexagonal prism where Euler's removal process creates a non-convex shape e.g. fails to preserve convexity. Give a detailed explanation.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried? Do you have any ideas of your own? Once we have a better idea of where you're struggling, we can help you better ^_^

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I believe it would be best to create the hexagonal prism intersection with the hexagonal pyramid such that the two lie on a different plane. From there, I am not sure where to perform the truncation...I suppose I am having the most difficult visualizing the result after the truncation, and THEN understanding if the result is convex or non-convex?